# I am calling functions inside a Dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a class where I have 3 simple functions and I package all of them in a dictionary.
The objective is to be able to loop through the dictionary calling the functions, however, I am getting several errors:

```
class Testa(object):
    def __init__(self, debt = None, equity = None):
        self.debt = debt
        self.equity = equity
    def tutu():
        print('hola')
    def foo(self):
        print('hello')
    def bar(self, debt=None, equity=None):
        return equity - debt

    variables = {'tutu':tutu,'foo':foo,'bar':bar}
```

The results I get are the following:

```
ra =Testa()
ra.variables['tutu']()
>>> hola
ra.variables['foo']()
>>> TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
ra.variables['bar'](debt = 300, equity=400)
>>> TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Any clues what it could be the problem? Thanks.-

Comment: Try reading the error message?

Comment: You're wondering why `self` is filled in when you call `ra.foo()`, but not when you call `ra.variables['foo']()`, is that it?

Answer (score 5):

`variables` is a class variable, but you're trying to call instance methods. Try instead initializing `variables` during object initialization:

```
class Testa(object):
    def __init__(self, debt = None, equity = None):
        self.debt = debt
        self.equity = equity
        self.variables = {'tutu': self.tutu, 'foo':self.foo, 'bar': self.bar}
    def tutu(self):
        print('hola')
    def foo(self):
        print('hello')
    def bar(self, debt=None, equity=None):
        return equity - debt
```

Comment: `def tutu():` may require `self` argument.

Comment: Hi Turn, Thank you so very much what idea works , it just needs self.variable to work. Thank you!!

Comment: Shouldn't you have `self.variables`?

Comment: @smac89 yup! Thanks!